# Did "The Other Guy" save Banner from the power of the Scepter?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, the-avengers-2012

I think this question [Why did Bruce Banner grab the scepter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79224/why-did-bruce-banner-grab-the-scepter/79249#79249) misses the point of the scene. Both the question and all of the answers.

That scene in *The Avengers* (2012) where they're all arguing in the lab and Bruce Banner picks up the Scepter...

In the shot immediately prior to that, Bruce says that:

> I hit a low point. I tried to end it. So I put a gun in my mouth and *the other guy* spat the bullet out.

The Scepter (which contains the Mind Stone) was obviously causing the arguments around it. And the second Bruce picks it up, the arguments end.

Was it that all of the arguments stopped because the bottomless well of anger that is the Hulk absorbed the power of the Scepter, saving Puny Banner again?

Comment: “the second Bruce picks it up, the arguments end” — I don't think we see exactly when Bruce picks it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arguments ended because everyone noticed Banner was holding the Scepter and were unnerved by that. Hulk *may* have absorbed the power, I highly, highly doubt it though, but that isn’t why everyone stopped arguing.

Notice throughout the moments prior to the reveal everyone has already stopped arguing and Fury and Black Widow have moved their hands to their guns? That’s because they’ve all noticed he’s picked the Scepter up and they are worried, especially knowing what he can become: the Other Guy.

> **Bruce Banner:** In case you needed to kill me, but you can't! I know! I tried! I got low. I didn't see an end, so I put a bullet in my mouth and the other guy spit it out! So I moved on. I focused on helping other people. I was good, until you dragged me back into this freak show and put everyone here at risk!
>
> *Banner slowly gets upset as he looks at Romanoff, who gets unnerved.*
>
> **Bruce Banner:** You wanna know my secret, Agent Romanoff? You wanna know how I stay calm?
>
> *BLACK WIDOW and Fury have their hands down to grab their guns.*
>
> **Steve Rogers:** Doctor Banner... put down the scepter.
>
> *BANNER LOOKS DOWN AND IS SHOCKED TO SEE HE'S HOLDING LOKI'S SCEPTER. The computer beeps. They all turn to it.*
>
> <sub>*The Avengers*</sub>

Note that Hulk isn’t the only angry one, they are *both* angry. That is Banner’s secret as he later tells Steve.

> **Steve Rogers:** Dr. Banner. Now might be a really good time for you to get angry.
>
> **Bruce Banner:** That's my secret, Captain. I'm always angry.
>
> <sub>*The Avengers*</sub>

The top answer on the linked question seems to explain why Bruce picks the Scepter up very well. He’s angry and can’t control his emotions and lot happens in a short period of time which gets him worked up leading to him picking up the Scepter.

The presence of the Mind Stone inside the Scepter manipulates those around it. Bruce and Tony has spent time studying it and so were most affected by it leading to Bruce picking the Scepter up on top of the emotional aspect above.

Comment: I didn't ask "how" 'The other guy' saved puny Banner.  But accepted, nonetheless, because that's evidently what the scriptwriters and director were going for.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins you asked if he saved Banner or not, my answer is saying he didn’t appear to have done and that the premise of your question, why they stopped arguing when he picks up the Scepter, is incorrect. If I’ve completely understood your question though let me know and I’ll edit as needed.